# How can I send an embed in discord.py to all servers the BOT is in

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have already been able to write the code in discord.py to see what servers my bot is in. Only issue is that I want a message in a embed to be sent to other servers that the bot is in. IF anyone could help that would be terrific. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all server ie all guilds. Then for each guild:
You'll need to get a channel for each server and then you can use `channel.send`. The method of selecting a channel depends on your use case.
To use name: `channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=<channel name>)`
To use id: `channel = guild.get_channel(<channel id>)`.

To send an embed, create an [embed object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed).
For example:

```py
embed_object = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Description", color=0xff0000)
embed_object.add_field(name="Field1", value="Value2", inline=False)
```

Then use `await channel.send(embed=embed_object)`.

Comment: that does not work here is my code
`@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def sendembed(ctx,*, msg):
      for server in client.guilds:
        for channel in server.text_channels:
          embed_object = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Description", color=0xff0000)
          embed_object.add_field(name="Field1", value="Value2", inline=False)
          await channel.send(embed=embed_object)`
@Suven Pandey

Comment: @coolcoderdude222 Could you edit the question to include code? It is difficult to read long pieces of code in comments, especially when indentation is relevant. Also include any error messages you receive, expected output and observed output.

Comment: Also, which version of discord.py are you using? `pass_context` is not required in newer versions and the version requiring `pass_context` is depreciated and probably doesn't work.